# 400 Problems parsing JSON - GitHub API and POSTMAN using OAuth

Tags: json, github, oauth, github-api, postman

I want to create a file in my private Repo via the GitHub API. 
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/contents/:path
```

I'm using Postman for testing and also already authorized via OAuth.

```
https://api.github.com/repos/user/reponame/contents/test.txt?message=Myfirstmessage&content=SGVsbG8gV29ybGQgaW4gQmFzZTY0IQ==
```

The error message is: "Problems parsing JSON"

But where exactly is the problem?

[image: Screenshot of my situation]

Comment: You are sending the data as a GET parameters, send it as the request body of a PUT request as stated in the docs. Also make sure your data is a valid json object.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use `choose file` from `body / binary`. I've just had the same problem with creating an issue on github. Putting attributes in `body / raw / json` solved the problem.