# Successful curl request fails with Java HttpURLConnection and Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, httprequest, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x, github-api

I am using Github's API to [update a file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file) in a repository. The follwing command works in `curl` (token field replaced):

```
curl -i -X PUT -H 'Authorization: token 2****************0' -d '{"path": "test6.txt", "message": "test", "sha":"863ba79d293acda68556bbddc1f97a29cb7b98bf","content": "dGVzdDM0Cg==", "
branch": "master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/pedro-roberto/test2/contents/test6.txt
```

The sha is updated and obtained from here `https://api.github.com/repos/pedro-roberto/test2/contents/test6.txt`
The content parameter is the base64 encoding of the file I want to use to update (in the command line `base64 file.txt`, in Java `byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(JsonArray_TO_UPLOAD.toString().getBytes()); String jsonInBase64 = new String(encodedBytes);`)

I have tried to do this request in Java but I fail with a response code `400:Bad request`

**Attempt 1**

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("path", "test6.txt" );
parameters.put("message","test");
parameters.put("sha", "863ba79d293acda68556bbddc1f97a29cb7b98bf" );
parameters.put("content", "dGVzdDM0Cg==");
 parameters.put("branch", "master");
URL url = new URL(https://api.github.com/repos/pedro-roberto/test2/contents/test6.txt);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization","token 2********************0");
con.setDoOutput(true);

 DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
out.writeBytes(ParameterStringBuilder.getParamsString(parameters));
out.flush();
out.close();
```

**Attempt 2**

```
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();;
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", "test6.txt");
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message","test"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sha", "863ba79d293acda68556bbddc1f97a29cb7b98bf"));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", "dGVzdDM0Cg=="));
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("branch", "master"));
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPut con2 = new HttpPut(link);
con2.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
con2.addHeader("Authorization","token 2*****************0");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(con2);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Don't know what to do to make this work. Please help!

EDIT:
I think the problem has to do with the way I build the query string. I was trying to make it work in Postman and it only worked when I stopped using parameters and used body/raw/JSON and sent the parameters as JSON (issue here: [400 Problems parsing JSON - GitHub API and POSTMAN using OAuth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487136/400-problems-parsing-json-github-api-and-postman-using-oauth?rq=1)). Don't know how to integrate this in Java though...

Comment: You can use one of the many open source JSON libraries.

Comment: managed to find a solution after some digging. answered my own question with a solution. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and errors, I managed to find a solution:

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("path", "test6.txt" );
parameters.put("message","test");
parameters.put("sha", "863ba79d293acda68556bbddc1f97a29cb7b98bf" );
parameters.put("content", "dGVzdDM0Cg==");
parameters.put("branch", "master");
HttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPut con2 = new HttpPut(https://api.github.com/repos/pedro-roberto/test2/contents/test6.txt);
con2.addHeader("Authorization","token 2******************0");

//tricky part
con2.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(parameters);
con2.setEntity(new StringEntity(json));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(con2);
```